# ReactJS superset Embedded sdk does not pass url params to the dashboard, any examples please

Tags: apache-superset

Trying the below code, the urlParam is not received by superset dashboard. Any references would be of a great help

const embed = async () => {
await embedDashboard({
id: '4b237d73-0470-4cc4-b6d3-9cd72f57237f', // given by the Superset embedding UI
supersetDomain: "https://staging.superset.com",

```
    mountPoint: document.getElementById("dashboard"), // html element in which iframe render
    height: '1000px',
    width: '1000px%',
  fetchGuestToken: () => fetchedToken,

    dashboardUiConfig: {
      hideTitle: false,
      hideChartControls: true,
      hideTab: true,
  
      urlParams: {
        accountid: 412
   },
    },
  })
}
```

Created Superset dashboard with urlParams and did not receive the params